# Threshold error Sharepoint Online even with indexed column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, threshold

I have a large list in SPO with 40k items and I have made some columns indexed.

When I create a plain view (no sort, group etc) with only filtering on one indexed column it somethings still gives a threshold error.

This is only when the filtered return data is above 400 items.

Is there some extra limitation to Sharepoint Online?

Comment: What is the condition in your filter? Contains? And what field type are you filtering?

Comment: It is just 1 "equals to" filter. I know how to handle threshold with filtering. But never had this issue..

Comment: And it is a "Single line of text" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found the issue. It was quite simple. The thresohold of the list is also counting the items of the recycle bin too. However when I checked it stated there were only for about 500  items in it. It really contained more than 100.000 items. This could be seen by site collection admin.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter on view with the condition greater eq [created column - 3] and some other column conditions.....logic to have at any given point of time the view should return less than 5k items.

Threshold issue is an impending issue over a decade in the SharePointing world.... Microsoft really needs fix this issue.

Please read the below article :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/detailed-insight-on-the-sharepoint-5000-list-view-threshold-limit-issue/

Comment: The filter is an "equals to". And I know the filter mostly returns less than 400 records this works properly, when result is above that (f.e. 402 items). It gets the threshold error. That is way less then 5k.

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with Calendar (Event) lists specifically, whereby recurring items would count as more than 1 actual item. But this only affected items past a certain date, it was really strange. We also couldn't open instances of the recurring events past that date, since that triggered a list-scan/threshold error somehow. We opened a ticket and got nowhere. They gave us the "this is by design" crap when they know there's a problem they can't fix.

We ended up having to migrate "older" items to a separate list. This fixed the issue, but now our users have to search multiple places if they need those things. Feels bad.

Not sure if this applies in your scenario, but just know that the threshold has some quirks (maybe you found a new one!). As long as the filter narrows the results down to below 5000 items, it *should* be good. This is 5000 items **total** returned in the view by the way, not just "per page".

Comment: Had a similar experience with a calendar list. It seemed that indexes are ignored by SharePoint in the calendars. Creating a plain list as a workaround worked, but needles to say it was far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a filtered view, make sure that the first column in the filter expression is indexed.

In addition, active "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" feature in the site.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" feature affects the threshold?